# How to take input from a file of ".in" format in c++? This code goes into infinite loop, but works fine for ".txt" file format

Tags: c++

```
#include<fstream.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{
    char x;
    ifstream f;
    f.open("A-small-practice.in"); 
    while(!f.eof())
    {
        f.get(x);
    cout<<x;
    }
}
```

the given ".in" file is opening with notepad++ but in "notepad", it shows the text in same line

Comment: You might want to start with getting this code into the current millennium: `<conio.h>` isn't needed for your code, `<fstream.h>` is not a standard header while `<fstream>` is, all standard classes live in namespace `std`, `main()` is required to return `int`, and you should never use `f.eof()` as a condition controlling your loop while reading.

Answer (score 3):

When the file you try open doesn't exist, the stream's `eof()` state will never be set. Thus, your program will go into an infinite loop. It is *always* an error to use `stream.eof()` as the only condition while reading a stream: a stream can go into fail state and never reach its end where it would set `stream.eof()` to `true`. Also you need to *always* check that your input was successful **after** you attempted to read.